# CMake-Configure: Permission Denied

Tags: cmake

I am trying to compile my Project with CMake, on one of my Computers it works perfectly (a Linux box), but the other one (Windows 7 Ultimate 64) has really problems.

I have tried multpiple generators:

MinGW (standalone and from CodeBlocks):
Error message:

(Just the part that should lead to a solution)

```
  f:/tools/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
  cannot open output file cmTryCompileExec.exe: Permission denied

  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Visual Studio 10 Professional
Error Message:

(Again only the Part that may be interesting, i have translated it from german)

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (MESSAGE):
  The C compiler "cl" is not able to compile a simple test program.
[...]
  1>ClCompile:

  1> testCCompiler.c

  1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: Datei
  "H:\yps_2\VISUAL\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTryCompileExec.exe" could not be opened.
```

I have Searched google and SO fpr days now and i think no one had some similar Problem like me...

I would be so glad if you could help me guys!

PS: There is another Issue on SO like mine, but it is unanswered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294011/permission-denied-errors-when-using-cmake

Comment: Are you running CMake and VStudio under the same user? Are you able to use VStudio normally with that user?

Comment: I can run Visual with that user, and i tried with and without Admin-rights (and Deleting the whole cache). Visual is able to Compile, if I open it and write a simple "Hello World".

Comment: Are the drives in question (f and h) by chance network shares? If yes, you should try to use a regular local drive.

Comment: They aren't, i think i have tried it in evry location (C:\, External Drives, different paritions...). If i Plug the drive into another PC i can configure it, but both do have the same OS, Visual, Rights, ... The files where created on the PC, where they dont work.

Comment: What cmake version are you using?

Comment: I use Version 2.8.6 (Downloaded just a few days ago)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you're computer is not infected with viruses: If any viruses modifying EXE files exist, they can be **the main cause** you can't write to your own EXE files. Scan your computer with an up-to-date antivirus.

Another problem can be your anti-virus trying to block EXE hijacks. If you're sure your computer is clean, try fully disabling your antivirus.

Another solutions that come to my mind are:

- Try right-clicking on Code Blocks or Visual Studio and choosing `Run as Administrator`.
- If you are executing from Command Prompt, make sure you do it in an administrative Command Prompt.
- Try putting the CMake and other related tools and also the output folder in your C:\ drive. Maybe you don't have quota or rights to access other drives?
- Try disabling all services you see are useless. Maybe some service has just locked the file without using it for no good reason.
- Try to dismount your H: volume and mount it again. (Either use `diskmgmt.msc` or use `fsutil volume dismount H:` and explore to mount it again)

Comment: Thank you! It has been the paranoid Firewall... I thought my firewall always tells me, if it blocks anything. Wrong thought, my mistake.

Comment: Hi @EGOrecords I'm having the same trouble as yours, how to see if my firewall block the permission or not, and how to work-around or disable it?

Answer (score 1):

Create the directory

```
H:\yps_2\VISUAL\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\
```

and make sure that you have write access.

Comment: The directory exists, i added write access, Same Error. I removed(by CMD) all Attributes that may be difficult, Same. I Removed the Directory, created it new, Same. I played around with Owners of the whole CMake-File tree, Always the same (just one difference: If I let the file be created new, it says "File cannot be closed", if it exists, "File cannot be opened", in MinGW "Permission Denied")