# CMake can't find fortran even tho i have it installed

Tags: cmake, fortran

I've been trying to edit cura by ultimaker [source code](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura) and trying to compile it using CMake but I can't seem to be able to do it even though I have fortran installed

(i use manjaro linux)

here is my CMake console output

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 10.1.0
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.1.0
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Building for Linux
Prepare lib and lib64 on Linux...
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'lib64': Permission denied

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake:33 (message):
  Could not find compiler set in environment variable FC:

  CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER-NOTFOUND.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  projects/openblas.cmake:3 (enable_language)
  CMakeLists.txt:58 (include)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/alsoussi/Projects/NewPrinter/cura/source/cura-build-environment/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

and here is my CMakeOutput.log file

(The log file is too large so here is a [github page](https://github.com/alsoussi070/Others/blob/master/CMakeOutput.log))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The error `Permission denied` looks like a permissions issue. Did you try running `cmake` as sudo?

Comment: What value are you using for the environment variable `FC`?

Comment: Thanks @squareskittles it worked, i just ran the program as root and it all went fine :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake-Configure: Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643069/cmake-configure-permission-denied)

Comment: If you need root to build the software, there is a problem. This shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Creating the Cura build env. on a rolling release is indeed troublesome, I should know Since I (one of the Cura developers) painstakingly created on on Manjaro. I can not provide you with a complete walk-through how to set-up, mainly because I can't remember the step anymore :-) But I would advise you to create a virtual python (3.6) env. and compile and install the Cura dependencies like libArcus, CuraEngine, Uranium from this environment, As of now you should not use the latest Sip but compile an older version from source, You would probably need to change some CMakeFiles as well

Comment: Because you will install everything in a virtual env you should not run into a permission denied error, if you do check the makefile and see why it points to the wrong folder. In my case if often happende because cmake found the system wide python instead of the virtual python version. There is also the issue that we use pyQt based on version Qt5.10.something a newer version like 5.14 will work, but might give you other errors.
Maybe an easier path is look into to docker-build environments https://hub.docker.com/r/ultimaker/cura-build-environment